# Running Lenovo laptop on AC power

Tags: laptop, battery, lenovo-laptop

I have Lenovo yoga 260 and its battery life isn't that good, and I don't want to make it worse. i tried saving power as much as possible but it wasn't very efficient. is there a way I could temporarily disable it and run it on AC power? Like the rest of laptops which got externally removable batteries and that could run on AC then by plugging the charger. (i.e I would save the battery usage for outdoor use only, and home use would be on AC power).

Comment: If you decide to open the laptop, this [IFIXIT -- Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 260 Repair Battery Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Lenovo+ThinkPad+Yoga+260+Repair+Battery+Replacement/105266) guide would be useful. Do remember to disable the battery before you open it though.

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo provides a mechanism to disable the battery which is typically used when you might want to change the battery or replace some other components. This is described in the [manual (link to user manual PDF file)](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/yoga260_ug_en.pdf) `p123`.

Note: This might not solve your problem if the disable described here does not hold across power-cycles (restarts).

From the user manual:

To disable the built-in battery, do the following:

1. Turn off your computer and disconnect the ac power adapter and all cables from the computer.
2. Turn on your computer. When the logo screen is displayed, immediately press F1 to enter ThinkPad Setup.
3. Select Config ➙ Power. The Power submenu is displayed.
4. Select Disable built-in battery and press Enter.
5. Select Yes in the Setup Confirmation window. The built-in battery is disabled and the computer turns off automatically. Wait three to five minutes to let the computer cool.

That last statement in point 5 about waiting for the computer to cool is for those planning to open the bottom and proceed to replace the battery.

I am unsure how long the battery will remain disabled with this method. A quick scan of the manual did not enlighten on a re-enable procedure. Maybe the re-enable is with the same steps to toggle the disable control off.

But, it could also be that the battery is re-enabled right after a power-cycle (i.e. the next time you reboot). I suspect this because I see the manual reference to this control for maintenance (like replacing memory, drive, etc.).

**Update for OP's comment:**

1. The disable control is in BIOS settings, so it will be useless unless it sticks to keeping the battery disabled across reboots.
2. Battery life is a function of power-cycles and real-time (all batteries eventually wear out even when unused). A battery on very low charge wears out faster. If the battery-disable method is usable, you could charge the battery somewhere between 50-60% before disabling it and then every some time, enable it, confirm charge is between 50-60% before re-disabling it. In fact, you should try using the battery for a few days before disabling it again.